# Converting updated column values to a table as rows

Tags: sql

```
ID  State   Name        Department         City
1   O       George      Sales              Phoenix
1   N       George      Sales              Denver
2   O       Michael     Order Process      San diego
2   N       Michael     Marketing          San jose
```

I got a situation that I need to convert the above tables values to the following format.(Consider the top row is column names)

```
ID  Column      OldValue       New Value
1   Department  Phoenix        Denver
2   Department  Order Process  Marketing
2   City        San diego      San jose
```

I.e  : I need to capture the changed column values for a table from its old and new records and record them in a different table.But the problem is we have many tables like that and the column names and no of columns are different for each table.

If anyone come with a solution that would be greatly appreciated..!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Shouldn't the first row say city under column?

Comment: Gaston and a_horse_with_no_name : Yes its in Sql server..<br> Hogan : yes it should be City.Thanks for the finding. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 ID  Column      OldValue      New Value
 1   City        Phoenix       Denver
 2   Department  Order Process Marketing
 2   City        San Diego     San jose
```

Here is the dynamic code:

```
DECLARE @sqlStm varchar(max);
DECLARE @sqlSelect varchar(max);

DECLARE @tablename varchar(200);
SET @tablename = 'testtable';

-- Assume table has ID column and State column.
SET @sqlSelect = ''
SET @sqlStm = 'WITH old AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM '+@tablename+'
   WHERE State=''O''
), new AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM '+@tablename+'
   WHERE State=''N''
)';

  DECLARE @aCol varchar(128)
  DECLARE curCols CURSOR  FOR
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = @tablename
      AND UPPER(column_name) NOT IN ('ID','STATE')

  OPEN curCols
  FETCH curCols INTO @aCol

  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @sqlStm = @sqlStm +
      ', changed'+@aCol+' AS
(
   SELECT n.ID, '''+@aCol+''' AS [Column], o.['+@aCol+'] AS oldValue, n.['+@aCol+'] AS newValue
   FROM new n
   JOIN old o ON n.ID = o.ID AND n.['+@aCol+'] != o.['+@aCol+']
)'
    IF LEN(@sqlSelect) > 0 SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect + ' UNION ALL '

    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect + '
SELECT * FROM changed'+@aCol

    FETCH curCols INTO @aCol

  END

  CLOSE curCols
  DEALLOCATE curCols

    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect + '
ORDER BY id, [Column]'


  PRINT @sqlStm+@sqlSelect

  EXEC (@sqlStm+@sqlSelect)
```

Which in my test output the following:

```
WITH old AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM testtable
   WHERE State='O'
), new AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM testtable
   WHERE State='N'
), changedName AS
(
   SELECT n.ID, 'Name' AS [Column], o.[Name] AS oldValue, n.[Name] AS newValue
   FROM new n
   JOIN old o ON n.ID = o.ID AND n.[Name] != o.[Name]
), changedDepartment AS
(
   SELECT n.ID, 'Department' AS [Column], o.[Department] AS oldValue, n.[Department] AS newValue
   FROM new n
   JOIN old o ON n.ID = o.ID AND n.[Department] != o.[Department]
), changedCity AS
(
   SELECT n.ID, 'City' AS [Column], o.[City] AS oldValue, n.[City] AS newValue
   FROM new n
   JOIN old o ON n.ID = o.ID AND n.[City] != o.[City]
)
SELECT * FROM changedName UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM changedDepartment UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM changedCity
ORDER BY id, [Column]
```

---

Original answer below:

I would do it like this -- because I think it is clearer than other ways which might be faster:

```
with old as
(
   Select ID, Name,Department,City
   From table1
   Where State='O'
), new as
(
   Select ID, Name,Department,City
   From table1
   Where State='N'
), oldDepartment as
(
   Select ID, 'Department' as Column, o.Department as oldValue, n.Department as newValue
   From new
   join old on new.ID = old.ID and new.Department != old.Department
), oldCity as
(
   Select ID, 'City' as Column, o.City as oldValue, n.City as newValue
   From new
   join old on new.ID = old.ID and new.City != old.City
)
select * from oldDepartment
union all
select * from oldCity
```

Depending on many things (size of tables and indexes etc) it might actually be faster than using pivots or cases or grouping.   It really depends on your data.  If this is a one-off run I'd just go for the easiest to grok.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply, and this might work if I have pre defined set of tables that needs to converted.But here my problem is I cannot have the column names mentioned with any statement,And the table also can be anything.If I just pass the table name my query or process should identify the rows and put the changed column values to the new table.

Comment: You did not state this as a requirement -- given this new requirement you have to use dynamic sql -- dynamic sql tends to be slow but will work for a 1 off or ad-hoc query.

Comment: Thank you Hogan for the quick response, I thought of writing dynamic sql only,but before that I would like to know if there is any othere better of implementing the same..Thank you so much for solution..will try that..

Comment: @Muthu - There is your dynamic query... enjoy.

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped us..Thanks again for the creating the dynamic statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach is probably to unpivot the data and then use aggregation.  This does require custom coding for each table, which you might be able to generalize by using some form a dynamic SQL.

For your particular example, here is an illustration of what to do:

```
select id, col,
       max(case when OldNew = 'Old' then value end) as OldValue,
       max(case when OldNew = 'New' then value end) as NewValue
from ((select ID, OldNew, 'Name' as col, Name as value
       from t
      ) union all
      (select ID, OldNew, 'Department' as col, Department as value
       from t
      ) union all
      (select ID, OldNew, 'City' as col, City as value
       from t
      )
     ) unpvt
group by id, col
having max(value) <> min(value) and max(value) is not null;
```

This is for illustration purposes.  The unpivot can be done more efficiently than using `union all`, particularly when there are many scans.  Here is a more efficient version, although the exact syntax depends on the database:

```
select id, col,
       max(case when OldNew = 'Old' then value end) as OldValue,
       max(case when OldNew = 'New' then value end) as NewValue
from (select ID, OldNew, cols.col,
             (case when cols.col = 'Name' then Name
                   when cols.col = 'Department' then Department
                   when cols.col = 'City' then City
              end) as value
      from t cross join
           (select 'Name' as col union all select 'Department' union all select 'City') cols
     ) unpvt
group by id, col
having max(value) <> min(value) and max(value) is not null;
```

This is more efficient because it will typically only scan your table once, rather than once for each column as in the `union all` version.

In either version, there is an implicit assumption that all the columns have the same character type.  This is implicit in the format you are converting to, where all the values are in a single column.